# Position subfloats (subfig package) of different types one besides two

Tags: horizontal-alignment, positioning, subfloats

I would like to make a table with one tabular top aligned left of two tikz figures. The problem seems somehow related to the floatrow package as without the result is, still not good, but better.

This is my minimal example. I inlcuded just demo pics as the behaviour is the same as for tikz pics:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top,footnoterule=none,footskip=.35\skip\footins}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\subfloat[t][]{
\begin{tabular}{cc}
Test&Test\\
Test&Test\\
Test&Test\\
Test&Test\\
Test&Test\\
Test&Test\\
Test&Test\\
Test&Test\\
Test&Test\\
Test&Test\\
Test&Test\\
Test&Test
\end{tabular}
}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\subfloat[t][]{
\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{}
}\\
\subfloat[t][]{
\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{}
}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Test}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Someone knows how to get caption (a) to be aligned with caption (b) while keeping the same setup?

Thanks in advance for the help!

EDIT:

I just realized that the actual outcome on my system would be helpful:
[image: The actual result of my code.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

This picture was produced by:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top,footnoterule=none,footskip=.35\skip\footins}
\usepackage{subfig}

    \begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
\subfloat[]{
\begin{tabular}[t]{cc}
Test&Test\\
Test&Test\\
Test&Test\\
Test&Test\\
Test&Test\\
Test&Test\\
Test&Test\\
Test&Test\\
Test&Test\\
Test&Test\\
Test&Test\\
Test&Test
\end{tabular}
}   &
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}
\subfloat[]{
\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{}
}\\
\subfloat[]{
\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{}
}
\end{tabular}
    \end{tabular}
\caption{Test}
\end{table}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was so close... I just forgot to put that top align in the second table...

Comment: @Mars, only for one tabular away :-)